# VBA for formula to values in a filtered range

Tags: vba, excel

Sometimes, I need to run a formula on a selection of a filtered range and then convert it to values, every time I want to `copy` and then `special paste values`, I must clear the filters first. I need a `macro` that will convert the formula to values without clearing the filters, I also want to use a shortcut key for this operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will allow this operation, the CTRL+M shortcut is available for this operation. Edit the macro to assign this shortcut key.

```
Sub PasteFilterValues()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    If Selection.Cells.Count = 1 Then

        Selection.Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Else

        Dim rng As Range

        Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        For Each cl In rng

            cl.Copy
            cl.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False

        Next cl

        rng.Select

    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Why copy and paste values? Surely it would be better to just set `cl = cl.value`?

Answer (score 0):

This should be faster than the other solution

```
Option Explicit

Sub fla2values(rng As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        c.Value = c.Value
    Next c
End Sub

Sub test_fla2values()
    fla2values Selection
End Sub
```